# Python print not showing until after loop and spam

Tags: python

I am making a simple question and answer code with a loop back but when I run the code it skips the first print and doesn't show anything. I'll fill in my name then question and then loop back to the start. It will then show me the script but it infinity spams it. I'm not sure how to get the first print to work and loop the program without the spam.

```
import random
import sys


def top():
    print ("Hello! I'm a magic eight ball! What's your name?")
    sys.stdout.flush()
name = raw_input()
print ("Welcome, " + name + "! Please ask your question!")
question = raw_input()
count = random.randint(1, 20)
print("Your question was:")
print(question)
print("my response is:")
if count == 1:
    print("It is certain")
if count == 2:
    print("decidedly so")
if count == 3:
    print("without a doubt")
if count == 4:
    print("Yes, definitely")
if count == 5:
    print("You may rely on it")
if count == 6:
    print("As I see it, yes")
if count == 7:
    print("Most likely")
if count == 8:
    print("Outlook good")
if count == 9:
    print("yes")
if count == 10:
    print("Signs point to yes")
if count == 11:
    print("Reply hazy try again")
if count == 12:
    print("Ask again later")
if count == 13:
    print("better not tell you now")
if count == 14:
    print("Cannot predict now")
if count == 15:
    print("concentrate and ask again")
if count == 16:
    print("Don'/t count on it")
if count == 17:
    print("No")
if count == 18:
    print("My sources say no")
if count == 19:
    print("Outlook not so good")
if count == 20:
    print("very dountful")
print("Would you like to ask another question?")
anotherquestion = raw_input()
while anotherquestion == 'yes':
    top()
else:
    print("Goodbye")
    sys.quit
```

Comment: You ought to look into using dictionaries for lookups, instead of having so many `if` statements :), e.g. `my_dict = {1: 'It is certain', 2: 'decidedly so', ...}`

Comment: It looks like you might have some experience with labels and jumps, or GOTO statements from other languages.  Python doesn't have those (by design).  In your code, `top` is a function, and is only called inside the `while` loop.  Think about it like this: every top level statement (i.e. everything not indented) is executed in order.  All a `def` statement does is say "remember the below code, and assign it this name" (*def*ine the function).  It doesn't do any execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use while to loop. Look below example
**code:**

```
import random
import sys

anotherquestion="yes"
while (anotherquestion=="yes"):
    print ("Hello! I'm a magic eight ball! What's your name?")
    sys.stdout.flush()
    name = raw_input()
    print ("Welcome, " + name + "! Please ask your question!")
    question = raw_input()
    count = random.randint(1, 20)
    print("Your question was:")
    print(question)
    print("my response is:")
    if count == 1:
        print("It is certain")
    if count == 2:
        print("decidedly so")
    if count == 3:
        print("without a doubt")
    if count == 4:
        print("Yes, definitely")
    if count == 5:
        print("You may rely on it")
    if count == 6:
        print("As I see it, yes")
    if count == 7:
        print("Most likely")
    if count == 8:
        print("Outlook good")
    if count == 9:
        print("yes")
    if count == 10:
        print("Signs point to yes")
    if count == 11:
        print("Reply hazy try again")
    if count == 12:
        print("Ask again later")
    if count == 13:
        print("better not tell you now")
    if count == 14:
        print("Cannot predict now")
    if count == 15:
        print("concentrate and ask again")
    if count == 16:
        print("Don'/t count on it")
    if count == 17:
        print("No")
    if count == 18:
        print("My sources say no")
    if count == 19:
        print("Outlook not so good")
    if count == 20:
        print("very dountful")
    print("Would you like to ask another question?")
    anotherquestion = raw_input()

print("Goodbye")
```

As stated in comment you can use dictonary rather then if her. see below sample

**code**

```
import random
import sys

anotherquestion="yes"
while (anotherquestion=="yes"):
    print ("Hello! I'm a magic eight ball! What's your name?")
    sys.stdout.flush()
    name = raw_input()
    print ("Welcome, " + name + "! Please ask your question!")
    question = raw_input()
    count = random.randint(1, 5)
    print("Your question was:")
    print(question)
    ANS_DIC={1:"It is certain",2:"decidedly so",3:"without a doubt",4:"Yes, definitely",5:"You may rely on it"}
    print("my response is:")
    print ANS_DIC[count]
    print("Would you like to ask another question?")
    anotherquestion = raw_input()

print("Goodbye")
```

Comment: What if you wanted the "anotherquestion = raw_input()" to have two option locations? 

like lets say if you wrote no, instead of closing the program it would give loud a new section of code.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you dont understand functions. The first `print` is inside a function (`def`). It will only execute when you call the function itself here:

```
top()
```

You can "work around" it like this:

```
def top():
    print ("Hello! I'm a magic eight ball! What's your name?")
    sys.stdout.flush()
print ("Hello! I'm a magic eight ball! What's your name?")
name = raw_input()
```

However i really advise you to look up on dictionaries instead of these `if`s, and also you can use `name = raw_input("Hello! I'm a magic eight ball! What's your name?\n")`.

Answer (score 0):

This problem comes down to indenting.  You have only indented the first two lines of code after the definition of function `top()`.  That means only the first two lines are *in* the function `top`.   You call `top()` in a loop—so it loops over and over the first two lines, whose effect is just to print the "hello" message.

Probably, you meant to indent everything above `anotherquestion=...`,  so that it's all part of `top`.

The next problem is that you have a line that asks whether the player wants to play again, but that line is not included in the loop—as a result, the loop will never end.    You can solve that one of two ways. One way is to have the "play again?" communication happen outside the function but *inside* the `while` loop. Another is to have it inside the the function—then you would need to ensure that the function `return`s the result, so that the `while` loop knows what the player's answer was, and uses this information.

On further reflection, your use of the name "top" for the function suggests that you are thinking of that function definition as a `goto`.  It is not.  `def` means "define a function" which is the same as saying "here is some code I will want you to perform later, but don't perform it yet, not until I tell you".  When `top()` is called, it performs the lines that were indented beneath `def top():` but, crucially, does **not** fall through to the subsequent lines (`name=...` and so on) at that time.